# GSHEET How do I Extract Text from formula for creating automatic cell reference

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

### The context :

Each time i need a cell reference from my other sheet, I need others cell reference from the same line but from different column.

I would like to automate those adding reference values depending on the first reference i add manually.

I have a sheet named **alpha** and a sheet named **beta**

I have a cell **A1** in **alpha** that refers to **beta A1**

I have this referred cell formula in **alpha A1** to have the value from **beta A1**
`=beta!A1`

### Objectif :

I would like to have in **alpha B2** the cell automatically filled-in by the value from **beta A7**
the equivalence of this refered cell formula
`=beta!A7`
Because the number seven will never change, only the column can change it could be:
`=beta!AC1`
so I will need `=beta!AC7` automatically populated.

### The Goal :

The goal is to extract from the formula in **alpha A1** all characters except number(s) by a formula (like SEARCH, LEN, from FORMULATEXT) to obtain
**=beta!A**
with this result, I will concatenate with a cell that has the value "7". to obtain the formula for the cell reference.

|  | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | `=beta!A1` | `=beta!A7` | `7` |
| 2 | `=beta!AC1` | `=beta!AC7` |  |

If anyone can give me this formula clue or a better way to reach my goal would be good
I tried the regex below but it removed the punctuation
`=REGEXREPLACE(FORMULATEXT(A1),"[^[:alpha:]]", "")&C1` where C1 is the value "7"
But i have all the need without the exclamation mark "!"

`=betaA7`
instead of
`=beta!A7`
Thank you

Comment: Did you try `INDIRECT()` function? like `=INDIRECT("beta!A" & C1)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### this is what you want

**Use this** to [`REGEXEXTRACT`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098245?hl=en) all the numbers and [`REGEXREPLACE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098245?hl=en) then with `""` nothing. and add `&$C1` the value in `C1`.

```
=REGEXREPLACE(A1, REGEXEXTRACT(A1, "[0-9]+"), "")&$C1
```

[image]

### A better way

See in `Beta!A1` we have a value of `Im beta A1`
And in `Beta!A7` we have a value of `Im beta A7`

[image]

And in `alpha!A1` we hane the formula `=beta!A1`

> **To get the value of `beta!A7` using the formula in `alpha!A1` as an input we use this formula in `beta!B1`**

```
=INDIRECT(REGEXREPLACE(SUBSTITUTE(FORMULATEXT(A1),"=",""), REGEXEXTRACT(SUBSTITUTE(FORMULATEXT(A1),"=",""), "[0-9]+"), "")&$C1)
```

*Explanation*
[`INDIRECT`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093377?hl=en)`(=beta!A1)`

[image]

### Even more simpler approach

**Use this formula directly**

```
=OFFSET(beta!A1,C1-1,0)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I should be more explicit because what I wrote is the formula, not the values inside the cells. So if i follow your formula and have a different data in cell. I have an error saying it's not a valid cell/range reference. What i have to manipulate is the formula in A1 not the result. The goal is to manipulate the formula of whatever the cell contains.

Comment: I tried replacing the cell by formulatext like '=INDIRECT(REGEXREPLACE(FORMULATEXT(A1), REGEXEXTRACT(FORMULATEXT(A1), "[0-9]+"), "")&$C1)' but gave me the same I think it's because it adds the equal at the first character

Comment: You tested option 1? did it work?

Comment: Just find a workaround but i'm sure there is something more straight forward: '=INDIRECT(REGEXREPLACE((REGEXREPLACE(FORMULATEXT(A1), REGEXEXTRACT(FORMULATEXT(A1), "[0-9]+"), "")&$C1),"(.{1})(.*)","$2"))'

Comment: This is what i did after you clarified ;) see the updated answer.

Comment: 1 = we have the formula as a cell value '=(REGEXREPLACE(FORMULATEXT(A1), REGEXEXTRACT(FORMULATEXT(A1), "[0-9]+"), "")&$C1)'
2 = we remove the equal sign of this result above '=REGEXREPLACE(B1,"(.{1})(.*)","$2")'
3 = we combine both to have the formula without the equal '=REGEXREPLACE((REGEXREPLACE(FORMULATEXT(A1), REGEXEXTRACT(FORMULATEXT(A1), "[0-9]+"), "")&$C1),"(.{1})(.*)","$2")'
4 = we include indirect to transform it as a formula '=INDIRECT(REGEXREPLACE((REGEXREPLACE(FORMULATEXT(A1), REGEXEXTRACT(FORMULATEXT(A1), "[0-9]+"), "")&$C1),"(.{1})(.*)","$2"))'
Does anyone as more simple way?

Comment: See Even more simple approach option 3 `=OFFSET(beta!A1,C1-1,0)`